# jQuery Generated List Based on Anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to generate a sub-nav based on anchors in the page with jquery. For some reason I'm not able to wrap my brain around how that would work. But essentially I have regular anchors scattered in my body like `<a id="section"></a>` and `<a id="section2"></a>`, etc…

So I would like to take each anchor `$("a:not([href])")` get the IDs and append each one to a definition list `<dd><a href="#section">Section</a></dd>`.

#### Nav Markup

`<dl class="sub-nav">
  <dt>Filter:</dt>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#">Top</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#section">Section</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#section2">Section2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#section3">Section3</a></dd>
</dl>`

Comment: Your selector seems to be correct. For generating the list, see the jQuery manual under [DOM Manipulation](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<a id="section"></a>
<a id="section2"></a>
<a id="section3"></a>
<a id="section4"></a>

<dl class="sub-nav"> 
    <dt>Filter:</dt> 
    <dd class="active"><a href="#">Top</a></dd> 
</dl>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a:not([href])").each(function(){
    $('dl.sub-nav').append("<dd><a href='#" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + $(this).attr('id') + "</a></dd>");
});
```

jsfiddle ->  http://jsfiddle.net/3Y7g3/18/

Comment: Simple and efficient, thanks ! I modded your code snippet a bit to display the text of the anchor instead of their URLs : `$(this).text()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it something like this.  Just loop over the anchors and build up the navigation tags.

```
var $nav = $("dl.sub-nav");

$("a:not([href])").each(function() {

    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    $a = $("a").prop("href", "#" + id).text(id);

    $nav.append(
        $("dd").append(
            $a
        )
    );
});
```

I'm assuming you started with the following markup.  Otherwise you could generate this too.

```
<dl class="sub-nav">
  <dt>Filter:</dt>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#">Top</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to first filter all of the elements that don't have an id assigned to them:

```
var anchors = $('a:not([href])').filter(function(){return this.id;});
```

You can simplify the above statement by adding the `id` attribute to your jQuery selector string:

```
var anchors = $('a[id]:not([href])');
```

Then all you need to do is simply iterate over this array and append definition nodes accordingly:

```
var $dl = $('dl.sub-nav');
anchors.each(function(){
  var $anchor = $("<a>"),
      id = this.id;
  $anchor.attr('href', "#" + id);

  // Capitalize the first letter of the anchor text as shown in your post
  $anchor.html(id.charAt(0).charAt(0).toUpperCase() + id.slice(1));

  $dl.append("<dd>" + $anchor.outerHTML() + "</dd>");
});
```